# How to show file explorer and import csv file using swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am new to IOS development, I am developing an iphone app where we need to import a csv file. For this I want to show a file explorer to the user to select csv file? I am clueless how to implement this feature? And the files are located in the mobile itself. I want to show a browse button, when the user clicks nn it, he can the select the files present in the mobile.

Comment: You better make one question at a time and post your code showing what you have accomplished so far and the error you've got.

Comment: iOS doesn't expose a file system to the user, how would the csv end up on the device in the first place?

Comment: @Leonardo Savio Dabus, sorry for multiple questions, I just created a two button to import and export. When a user click on import button, the user needs to select the file. I am clueless how to proceed

Comment: you can save the files at the documents folder

Comment: @Leonardo Savio Dabus, Can we show the dialog box to select the file ?